# Free Java servlet hosting?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7, hosting

I finished to build my semester project and now I need to show it to the lecturer.

This project is a MVC server ..

It contains Java Servlet (Contoller),  JSP for the views.

I'm using Hibernate 3.6.4 for the Model (DAO)  layer and MySQL for the database.

And of course Tomcat server 7.

Is there a free hosting service where I can host my project?

Comment: This question doesn't belong to SO. This site is for programming related specific questions, no the ones about hosting or hardware.

Comment: I had recently the same question and did some research about it http://progrnotes.blogspot.com/2017/03/free-java-hosting-options-and-heroku.html

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/heroku/

Answer (score 30):

Try Openshift. https://www.openshift.com
With 3 free gears you can setup Tomcat/JBoss and MySQL.
It can be integrated with Eclipse and hot deployments are possible (via git). Also, to MySQL, you can add PhpMyAdmin controller.

Comment: Due of the overwhelming popularity of our OpenShift Online (Next Gen) platform, registrations have been paused

Comment: Openshift next gen is no longer generous like its earlier version. The starter addition is just for educational purpose and is not for any serious business.

Answer (score 11):

[Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/) has a [free usage tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) that you can use without charge for 12 months. You could use an EC2 micro instance to host Tomcat and an RDS instance for MySQL. Alternatively you could install MySQL in the same EC2 instance as Tomcat.

Comment: @Devid i have one question they are asking credit card detail when sing in time.its mandatory to use free service if yes then how they are giving free service ?

Comment: @PrakashMadhak They require that you provide a credit card but will not charge it unless you use features outside of the free tier. They probably do this to ensure that people don't abuse the free tier by creating multiple accounts using different emails.

Answer (score 7):

Check [cloudbees.com](https://www.cloudbees.com/). It allows you to deploy you WAR files for free. Just make sure you compile your project  with the same java version as they(1.6 not sure about it).