# How to run java application(war file) using tomcat 8 on cloud? & Where?

Tags: java, mysql, apache

I am using Tomcat server for my Java application & MySQL as the back end. Right now I am running it through local server(LAN). Now I want to shift my application to the web and run as a web application. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free Java servlet hosting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734616/free-java-servlet-hosting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no difference with tomcat 7,just put up you project's war file to the "webapps" directory，then set up the tomcat server.