# Launch a Java web application on internet

Tags: java, web, netbeans

I have a project made with Eclipse or Netbeans, it's a Java web application, I would like to deploy this application on web, using a free server, It's only a trial for to learn how function, Could you explain how I can do it ?

Comment: You need to find a site which offers free web hosting with the appropriate web/application server like tomcat or jboss. Then you'll have to deploy your `.war` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an application server that supports Java. Tomcat, JBoss, Jetty, any one who fits your needs. Then, just upload your war file into webapps folder (for Tomcat) and it will do the work for you.
You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734616/free-java-servlet-hosting) some free or trial services that should be enough for learning.

Then, when you kickass deploying web apps, just subscribe some java application server service or, as I do, rent a VPS and install all you need. Give you some more work, but much more flexible. I've been using [ovh VPS](https://www.ovh.com/us/vps/) and for the price, I'm very happy. Good luck ;)